# Blank space on Less function

Tags: css, less

I've got a white space between the delay number and the "s" for seconds in this Less function. Obviously, when render, it's invalid.

Why is this blank space added, and how to get rid of it?

**INPUT:**

```
.generateDelay(5);
.generateDelay(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
    &:nth-child(@{i}) { 
        animation-delay: (.25*@i)s;
    }
    .generateDelay(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
animation-delay: 0.25 s;
animation-delay: 0.5 s; //etc
```

PS:

I couldn't solve it with the marked duplicated questions. If I try to multiply within a new variable, it says it's not defined. And I cannot multiply inside a ~" ", as it's converted to string.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Just don't miss that the proper solution is either `.25s*@i` or `unit(.25*@i, s)` and not the `~""` stupidity.

Comment: @seven-phases-max thanks, the `unit()` thing was what I was looking for. That answer should be marked as the better solution imo

Comment: Personally I also critic the unit method as bloating and never necessary. `.25s * @i` is the most clean and semantically accurate (because it's really *nothing but* `@i times of 250 milliseconds`). It's important to remember in CSS (and thus in Less) a unit is a part of value and not some kind of "externally imposed string suffix". The method is what you find at the official [docs](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-loops-feature) (and you won't find any `unit` examples there because the function is never necessary in cases like this and exists only for much more excotic use-cases).